# Kafka Streams: Stream tasks moving across app instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Consider stream application setup with an input topic of 6 partitions that has a state store.  Assume there is a constant inflow of over 5 million records each hour.  If the application is run on a single node, the state for all the incoming records remains in the same node.  Now, if we add another instance on a different node, I assume it would equally balance the partitions between the two instances (assume we set the max threads as 3 in each instance).

I guess my question is when the rebalance occurs and if a partition instance moves from one to another one and vice versa, this will cause the state store to be restored for those partitions on their respective instances and that takes time.  Wouldn't the frequent shuffle of the partitions between the instances (especially of significant volume) due to the rebalance be a major overhead and impact the streaming performance.  I am not sure if it is possible to completely prevent the rebalance (which I understand is for the load balancing benefit), but would this not prevent scaling up with multiple instances for the same topic that uses the store?

Comment: could you please clarify which is your main concern ?

Comment: Say partition 0 was running on instance 1 and partition 4 on instance 2, during rebalance if both switches between the instances, meaning partition 0 to instance 2 and partition 4 to instance 1, this causes the state store to be restored and let's assume another rebalance occurs and they switched back, causing another state restoration which will take time to restore.  While it is flexible to scale horizontally , the time of restoring the state might impact the stream performance and that is the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams uses its own implementation of `PartitionAssignor` (not the default one used by `KafkaConsumer`) and implements a sticky assignment strategy. During rebalance, it's known which partitions were assigned to what `KafkaStreams` instance and we try to reassign partitions to the same instance if possible to avoid state movement. Load balancing also plays a role to allow for scaling scenarios of course.